# Convert Latin to e.g Gothic

Tags: string-manipulation, character-encoding

Sorry for the very simple question but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

I have a list of Latin letters, e.g. {a, b, c, d...}. I want to convert them to the corresponding Gothic letters. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/how-one-can-programmatically-transform-a-text-into-gothic-doublestruck-or-some

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a little improvement to AGML's solution, which will work for upper and lower case symbols/strings:

```
Clear[makeGothic];
makeGothic[ s_Symbol] := makeGothic[ ToString@s ]
makeGothic[ s_String ] /; StringLength@s == 1 && Not@StringFreeQ[s, Alphabet[]] := 
    FromCharacterCode[ 
        ToCharacterCode["\[GothicA]"] + ToCharacterCode[s] - ToCharacterCode["a"]
    ]
makeGothic[ s_String ] /; StringLength@s == 1 && Not@StringFreeQ[s, Capitalize@Alphabet[]] := 
    "\\[GothicCapital" <> s <> "]" // ToExpression

makeGothic /@ (Capitalize@Alphabet[] ~ Join ~ Alphabet [])
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

```
toGothicLetters = Association[System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$GothicLetters /. 
    Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[StringReplace[b, "\\mathfrak{" | "}" -> ""], a]];

toGothicLetters /@ Join[CharacterRange["a", "z"], CharacterRange["A", "Z"]] // StringJoin
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
thelist = {a, b, c, d}

ToGothic[thischar_] := 
 "\\[Gothic" <> ToUpperCase[SymbolName[thischar]] <> "]" // ToExpression

Map[ToGothic, thelist]
```

This works, but it's pretty hacky. Is there a better way?

Edit: I escaped the slash to avoid an (apparently harmless?) error message.